# How do I find locals in VS2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have installed VS2013 recently. Today I tried to track my variable values but was unable to find the little window which usually appears in the bottom of the IDE. In previous versions of VS, I used to go to : Debug-Windows-Locals.
Is there an option in the settings window which I should enable or did I miss something else?

Comment: It is still there in the exact same place.

Comment: Its only there when you debug. `Ctrl-D, L` is the default shortcut

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's one confusion here: **It's only visible in the debug menu when you're debugging**.

Not debugging:

[image]

Debugging:

[image]

Comment: I dont' know how on earth I missed that!, TNX, I will accept your answer soon.

Comment: @esner_togo No problems glad I could help, had me confused for a second lol.

Answer (score 3):

While debugging you can see the option for the local window:

[image]

I don't think its moved anywhere!

Also, it appears automatically (for me anyway) at the bottom of VS, near where you would see "Output", "Error" information etc.

Comment: What version are you running, Ultimate?

Comment: I am running Professional and it is there.

Comment: mine's professional, but ive seen it there on other versions